Validate Lightning Email template before sending
I have a situation where some email templates contain both:

Merge fields from Contact object
Placeholders for the sales agent to input before sending (contextual values)

Is there any scope where I can intercept the email being sent for validation ensuring the placeholders are not left unpopulated (Apex, Flow, etc.)
Thanks in advance!
